# How to automatically create missing folders for ImageOutputStream?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I'm trying to save a  `jpg` images with custom compression. Therefore using `ImageWriter` as follows:

```
ImageOutputStream os = new FileImageOutputStream(new File(filenamepath));

ImageWriter jpgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
ImageWriteParam jpgWriteParam = jpgWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(1f);
jpgWriter.setOutput(os);
```

Problem: the code only works if the folder given in `filenamepath` already exists, and throws `FileNotFoundException` if folder is missing.

Question: how could I implicit let the writer create the target folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create it first. [`FileImageOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/FileImageOutputStream.html) won't create the file if it doesn't exist.

This can easily be done using [Java NIO.2 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) with [`Files.createDirectory(dir)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectory-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-). This method checks if the directory already exists and, if not, creates it.

> Creates a new directory. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the directory if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the directory.

If you need to create all the parent directories as well, you can use [`Files.createDirectories(dir)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-):

> Creates a directory by creating all nonexistent parent directories first.

Sample code:

```
File.createDirectories(Paths.get(filenamepath));
```

---

Note that it is a better idea to use Java NIO.2 API instead of old `createNewFile()`: you can easily handle the rights to give to the created directories. Also, it forces the developer to handle the case where the directories couldn't be created (and gives more information as to why, instead of just having `true` or `false` like in the `createNewFile()` case).

Comment: Does this also apply to any parent and child directories in the filename path?

Comment: @membersound In that case, you can use createDirectories, I edited with that.

Comment: Ok but this method would require a `Path`, but I need a `File` object explicit for feeding the `FileImageOutputStream`. So then I'd have to create both a File and a Path object?

Comment: You can get a Path with the static factory `Paths.get`. I editeds

Comment: So and how can I get the `File` object fro passing it to the `OutputStream` from `Path`?

Comment: @membersound The rest of the code is exaclty like in your question, no need to change anything.

Comment: So I'm gonne stick creating the `new File()` as usual, and additionally add the `File.createDirecories(..)` statement before, if I got you right?

Comment: @membersound Yep. You could use `Path.toFile()` instead of `new File()` but that's the same.

Comment: Good point on why it's better to use NIO.2! Exceptions when things fail are good. However, I belive the pre-NIO equivalent would be `File.mkdirs()`?

Comment: @haraldK It would be yes.